# How to "multicast" an async iterable?

Tags: javascript, async-await, observable, ecmascript-2016

Can an `async` generator be somehow broadcast or multicast, so that all its iterators ("consumers"? subscribers?) receive all values?

Consider this example:

```js
const fetchMock = () => "Example. Imagine real fetch";
async function* gen() {
  for (let i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    const res = await fetchMock();
    yield res.slice(0, 2) + i;
  }
}
const ait = gen();

(async() => {
  // first "consumer"
  for await (const e of ait) console.log('e', e);
})();
(async() => {
  // second...
  for await (const é of ait) console.log('é', é);
})();
```

Iterations "consume" a value, so only one or the other gets it.
I would like for both of them (and any later ones) to get every `yield`ed value, if such a generator is possible to create somehow. (Similar to an `Observable`.)

Comment: Is it possible for you to change the design so that `gen` accepts callback functions that are applied to each yielded thing? Is there a specific reason you want / need to use generators?

Comment: @kingkupps Yes `gen` could accept a callback.
I'm using async generators because they are a built-in feature of JS, otherwise I would use an `Observable` for this but I thought they do almost the same thing (except for the ability to "multicast")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not easily possible. You will need to explicitly [tee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)) it. This is similar to [the situation for synchronous iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46416266/1048572), just a bit more complicated:

```
const AsyncIteratorProto = Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(async function*(){}.prototype));
function teeAsync(iterable) {
    const iterator = iterable[Symbol.asyncIterator]();
    const buffers = [[], []];
    function makeIterator(buffer, i) {
        return Object.assign(Object.create(AsyncIteratorProto), {
            next() {
                if (!buffer) return Promise.resolve({done: true, value: undefined});
                if (buffer.length) return buffer.shift();
                const res = iterator.next();
                if (buffers[i^1]) buffers[i^1].push(res);
                return res;
            },
            async return() {
                if (buffer) {
                    buffer = buffers[i] = null;
                    if (!buffers[i^1]) await iterator.return();
                }
                return {done: true, value: undefined};
            },
        });
    }
    return buffers.map(makeIterator);
}
```

You should ensure that both iterators are consumed at about the same rate so that the buffer doesn't grow too large.

Comment: Wow, thank you, indeed it's not trivial. Hoping to find a good library that contains this and other abstractions for async iterators.

Comment: @ᆼᆺᆼ I guess you'd find something like this in a CSP library with channels

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using [Highland](https://caolan.github.io/highland/) as an intermediary. From the docs:

> A stream forked to multiple consumers will pull values, one at a time, from its source as only fast as the slowest consumer can handle them.

```js
import _ from 'lodash'
import H from 'highland'

export function fork<T>(generator: AsyncGenerator<T>): [
    AsyncGenerator<T>,
    AsyncGenerator<T>
] {
    const source = asyncGeneratorToHighlandStream(generator).map(x => _.cloneDeep(x));
    return [
        highlandStreamToAsyncGenerator<T>(source.fork()),
        highlandStreamToAsyncGenerator<T>(source.fork()),
    ];
}

async function* highlandStreamToAsyncGenerator<T>(
    stream: Highland.Stream<T>
): AsyncGenerator<T> {
    for await (const row of stream.toNodeStream({ objectMode: true })) {
        yield row as unknown as T;
    }
}

function asyncGeneratorToHighlandStream<T>(
    generator: AsyncGenerator<T>
): Highland.Stream<T> {
    return H(async (push, next) => {
        try {
            const result = await generator.next();
            if (result.done) return push(null, H.nil);
            push(null, result.value);
            next();
        } catch (error) {
            return push(error);
        }
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
const [copy1, copy2] = fork(source);
```

Works in Node, browser untested.

Comment: Does this work in browsers or only on Node?

Comment: I assume Node only, because of how `highlandStreamToAsyncGenerator` is implemented.

Answer (score -1):

I built a library to do this here: https://github.com/tjenkinson/forkable-iterator

Means you can do something like:

```
import { buildForkableIterator, fork } from 'forkable-iterator';

function* Source() {
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  return 'return';
}

const forkableIterator = buildForkableIterator(Source());

console.log(forkableIterator.next()); // { value: 1, done: false }

const child1 = fork(forkableIterator);
// { value: 2, done: false }
console.log(child1.next());
// { value: 2, done: false }
console.log(forkableIterator.next());

// { value: 'return', done: true }
console.log(child1.next());
// { value: 'return', done: true }
console.log(forkableIterator.next());
```

If you no longer need to keep consuming from a fork providing you loose references to it there also shouldn’t be a memory leak.