# In Javascript, is there a way to use an iterator twice?

Tags: javascript, iterator

Given an [iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#the_iterator_protocol) in Javascript, is there an efficient way to iterate it twice?

I'm looking for something like the [`ReadableStream.tee()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream/tee) method, but for any kind of `Iterator`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46416266/how-to-clone-an-iterator-in-javascript

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26179693/how-to-clone-es6-generator and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23848113/is-it-possible-to-reset-an-ecmascript-6-generator-to-its-initial-state for generators specifically

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation I've come up myself.

```js
function tee(iterable) {
    const iter = iterable[Symbol.iterator]()
    const [iter1, buffer1] = make()
    const [iter2, buffer2] = make()
    return [iter1, iter2]

    function next() {
        const { value, done } = iter.next()
        if (!done) {
            buffer1.push(value)
            buffer2.push(value)
        }
    }

    function make() {
        const buffer = []
        const iter = {
            next() {
                if (buffer.length === 0) {
                    next()
                }
                if (buffer.length > 0) {
                    return { value: buffer.shift() }
                }
                return { done: true }
            },
            [Symbol.iterator]() { return iter },
        }
        return [iter, buffer]
    }
}

// Example usage
const someMap = new Map([['a',"A"],['b','B']])
const someIterator = someMap.values()

const [iter1, iter2] = tee(someIterator)
[...iter1] // ["A", "B"]
[...iter2] // ["A", "B"]
[...someIterator] // [] as it's exhausted by now
[...iter1] // []
[...iter2] // []
```

Comment: Very nicely done!

Comment: @trincot [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78084697/450383) following Python's [tee](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) is even better!